# Need Lucene 4.1.0 source jars or javadoc jars (to make developing with Lucene 4.1.0 in Eclipse usable)

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

How/where do I obtain the source jars (or javadoc jars) for Lucene 4.1.0?

I've just downloaded and untarred the latest version of Lucene from one of the mirrors listed at http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/java/4.1.0, both `lucene-4.1.0-src.tgz` and `lucene-4.1.0.tgz`.  I could easily add the 42 jars found in the latter to my Eclipse project.

Adding javadoc or sources is proving more vexing.

In the past, I somehow got a hold of source jars (each of which could be attached in Eclipse to the corresponding byte-compiled jar via Project.right.click/Properties/Java_Build_Path/Libraries).  Since the sources already contain javadoc, that's all I needed to get hints from Eclipse upon hovering over types and method calls and life was good. (Plus I could always step into the source when needed).

Now, I poked my nose into lucene-4.1.0-src, just to see.  No jars (src or otherwise), of course.  But trying to compile requires me first to set up "ivy" (excuse me?)  Since I'm on Fedora, after doing the prescribed `ant ivy-bootstrap` I followed some extra instructions to make ivy sort of work (essentially it boils down to `echo rpm_mode=false >> ~/.ant/ant.conf`).  Still, `ant jar-src` at the top level fails ("/src/java doesn't exist"). `ant clean compile` does a bit better, but `ant jar` fails (invalid manifest).

Alternatively, `lucene-4.1.0.tgz` comes with 95MB of docs; How do I connect the 42 Lucene jars in Eclipse with these 5458 files totaling 95MB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build tool with Eclipse [integration](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) because it not only adds all necessary libraries automatically, but also can automatically download all sources and javadocs of libraries being used.

Small lifehack: personally me and my team use maven's `pom.xml` even in projects, where we use other build's capabilities (`ant` or IDE's specific).

If you don't want to bother with maven, I'd like to introduce very helpful resources: http://search.maven.org/

Here you can search (and find) almost any maven's libraries, with sources and javadocs.

F.e. you can search for `lucene-core` and see what happen:
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|lucene-core

On the `Download` tab you'll see `sources.jar` and `javadoc.jar` which you can download and add to your project.

Comment: the third paragraph is awesome -- thanks a million. I indeed don't want to bother with maven. Last time I touched it, it went on trying to build the entire universe for hours, apparently trying to download every piece of java code ever written by mankind in the process.

Comment: I just thought I would add a quick note about this. First, by (simple-)searching for lucene on http://search.maven.org, I saw that the latest version was 4.2.0. Then I looked for all "important" packages with the advanced search `g:"org.apache.lucene" AND v:"4.2.0"`. Finally I selected "lucene-core" and the other packages I need, all in the sources.jar version, and curl-ed them all.  BTW I'm not sure why one would want the javadoc.jar, as they are huge.