# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.Archive error when running hector example code

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I have included all the jars found in the hector-core-1.1-2 folder. A are there any other jars i haven't included. 
Things I have tried. 
1) Clearing netbeans cache
2) Downloading org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.Archive.jar and including it in my path only to have another exception like `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source).....` about a class missing.
3) Reinstalling Netbeans. I think that was a stupid thing to do.

The exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.Archive
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at me.prettyprint.hom.CassandraPersistenceProvider.createScanner(CassandraPersistenceProvider.java:55)
at me.prettyprint.hom.CassandraPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(CassandraPersistenceProvider.java:49)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
```

my question i guess is, what jars do i need to download in order to connect to cassandra from netbeans using hector and also hector object mapper?

Comment: For future users with same problem, please download the correct jars referenced on http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/xbean/xbean-finder-shaded/4.5/xbean-finder-shaded-4.5.jar

Comment: please add your comment in the answer section, your comment helped me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `xbean-finder.jar` into your project.

But for preventing such issues in the future, I would recommend using special search engines, f.e. http://search.maven.org. It is very helpful resource for searching of necessary jar-files, maven's dependencies, sources, javadocs and so on.

P.S. Search string for your case:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3Aorg.apache.xbean.finder.archive.Archive

Comment: I have tried that already that's why I said that every time I download the missing jar, another exception is flashed for yet another class not found. so far i have downloaded as many as 5 jars and each time a new exception is raised. I don't want to have a project with a thousand jars downloaded from a thousand sites which will become unmanageable. It seems like all this jars should be contained in a package which I am trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.hectorclient|hector-core|1.1-2|bundle). According to `pom.xml` file `hector-core` has lots of dependencies, each of which can have its own dependencies... Thus I would recommend using maven file either for the building of your project, or at least for downloading of all hector's dependencies at once.

Comment: BTW, please consider that for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266755/655756) person the same approach was very helpful

Comment: thenks you all I managed to download all the jars by name from searching maven.org like n1ckolas and the rest of you have suggested. prior to my problem I had developed a strictly no maven policy/attitude but but the previous couple of days head scratching-wanna-smash the pc feeling ncdf exceptions have given me no choice but to learn how to integrate maven in my projects.